# How do I access EC2 Instance Storage from Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage

I'm launching a fresh Amazon EC2 image running Amazon Linux (Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03.2 (HVM)). I'm using a larger type (e.g. m3.large) which comes with 1 x 32 (SSD) Instance Storage according to the launch page.

However, I'm not able to find that storage anywhere. In documentation that I found it mentioned that it should be listed with `lsblk` and mounted in `/media`, but `/media` is empty and `lsblk` only gives me the 8GB root disk:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

Anyone an idea how to access my 'default' instance storage that I get with my instance?

Answer (score 0):

I have since received a solution via the AWS Forums. See here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=565737